# Calling a function and each call works simultaneously and not in a queue

Tags: python

Hi i would like to know what method i could use to call a function a few times and each call is processed in parallel and NOT in a queue based processing.

Something along this line

```
import time
import random

def run(incoming):
        time.sleep(5)
        print incoming
        break
while True:
    hash = random.getrandbits(128)
    run(hash)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You'd need to look at either multithreading or multiprocessing. If it's a simpler function, threading may do the trick, but it's not simple programming, really. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @TheSoundDefense its not overly difficult either ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley well, not in Python, I suppose.

Comment: What do you actually want to be done in parallel here? Generating the hash, or some kind of processing done with the hash? If you're doing processing with the hash, is it CPU-bound (like mathematical calculations) or I/O-bound (like network calls or reading/writing to the disk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
import random
import threading

def run(incoming):
        time.sleep(5)
        print incoming


while True:
    hash = random.getrandbits(128)
    threading.Thread(target = run,args = (hash,)).start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

note that this is restricted  by the gil where it interleaves the processes ... but for your purposes you can probably call it parallel and since your thread count keeps growing it may eventually break down

there are much better ways to do this lets check it out

```
def do_hard_work(hash):
    time.sleep(1)
def Run(data_pipe):
   while True:
       while data_pipe.poll():
            hash = data_pipe.recv()
            if hash == "QUIT":
                  break
            threading.Thread(target=do_hard_work,args=(hash)).start()
            time.sleep(1)

local,remote = multiprocessing.Pipe()
worker_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run,args=(local,))
worker_process.start()
while True:
    remote.send(random.getrandbits(128))
    time.sleep(1)
    if some_condition:
         remote.send("QUIT")
         break
```

Comment: How do i kill the thread after the it has been processed. Thanks

Comment: it dies when it exits the function ... but since your function sleeps longer it accumulates (IE 5 child threads before the first one finishes)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Your `multiprocessing` example doesn't make sense in it's current state. `multiprocessing.Process(local)` doesn't make sense; you're just passing one end of a pipe into it, without passing it a target function. You also never call `start` on the process. I'm assuming that `Run` is what's supposed to run in the worker process, which means there's no reason to create a `Thread` object in there.

Comment: calling thread just lets it process many at once ... like OP wants... on the other parts your right ... I was distracted while answering this ...